# How can I optimise this slow PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

I have tracked the cause of a slow API endpoint to an SQL query and cannot for the life of me optimise it.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT "Views".*, "Show".*, "Episode".*, "User".* FROM "Views"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Shows" AS "Show" ON "Show"."id" = "Views"."ShowId"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Episodes" AS "Episode" ON "Episode"."id" = "Views"."EpisodeId"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Users" AS "User" ON "User"."id" = "Views"."UserId"
WHERE "Show"."tvdb_id" IN (259063,82066,258823,265766,261742,82283,205281,182061,121361)
AND "User"."id"=29;
```

It takes between 3000-4200ms to complete. The result of an EXPLAIN ANALYZE on the query can be found here: http://explain.depesz.com/s/J9R

**EDIT:** I have also tried separating the IN() into ORs:

```
SELECT "Views".*, "Show".*, "Episode".*, "User".* FROM "Views"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Shows" AS "Show" ON "Show"."id" = "Views"."ShowId"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Episodes" AS "Episode" ON "Episode"."id" = "Views"."EpisodeId"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Users" AS "User" ON "User"."id" = "Views"."UserId"
WHERE
    "Show"."tvdb_id"=259063 OR
    "Show"."tvdb_id"=82066 OR
    "Show"."tvdb_id"=258823 OR
    "Show"."tvdb_id"=265766 OR
    "Show"."tvdb_id"=261742 OR
    "Show"."tvdb_id"=82283 OR
    "Show"."tvdb_id"=205281 OR
    "Show"."tvdb_id"=182061 OR
    "Show"."tvdb_id"=121361 
AND "User"."id"=29;
```

I have tried creating indexes on the columns referenced in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but that resulted in marginal gains (if anything). What's interesting is I also tried reducing the `WHERE x IN` to a single `WHERE x = y` and this instantly improved the situation, responding instead in 200-300ms. So how would I go about optimizing the IN statement?

Thanks!

Comment: also show us how indexes are looking atm

Comment: @Jester Thanks! I'll update my question but I have already tried separating the IN() into several "Show"."tvdb_id"=259063 OR etc. it saved 10-20ms at most :(

Comment: I'd try changing the order of the WHERE clauses, assuming that the restricting by user.id is a smaller number of records than the IN ?

Comment: Do you have an index on tvdb_id?

Comment: also tell us roughly how much records you have in each table and also show all table definitions maybe there is room to improve there if you can scale the were statement down by filtering the tables in sub selects

Comment: @Mihai Thanks, I've added an index ```CREATE INDEX shows_tvdb_id_index ON "Shows" USING btree (tvdb_id);``` but unfortunately it was no quicker :(

Comment: @Jester record counts are Shows: 1045 / Views: 6908 / Episodes: 53434 / Users: 32

Also, the Tables concerned are detailed here https://gist.github.com/Illizian/e00aed6dec146e919c93

Comment: Make sure the join columns are of the same type.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Answer (score 0):

Try to make combined index on table Views on fields ShowId, EpisodeId, UserId together.

```
CREATE INDEX Views_idx ON Views
  USING btree (ShowId, EpisodeId, UserId);
```

ps. explain link is wrong, it's for some other query

Best regards,

nele

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have increased the performance either :( thanks!

Comment: can you provide correct explain output for this query?

Comment: pretty sure the link is correct, I've done another http://explain.depesz.com/s/bXu and also updated the gist with the raw query and output (here https://gist.github.com/Illizian/e00aed6dec146e919c93#file-explain-sql)